# Haskell getArgs type is `Char` instead of `[Char`]

Tags: list, haskell, char, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get command line arguments to work with Haskell.  I currently have

```
args ← getArgs
-- opens text file, uses handle for text
handle ←  openFile args ReadMode
```

However, when I compile I am told that args is of type `Char`, not `[Char]`, therefore, I cannot open the file. Is there another way to take in arguments in Haskell or am I taking mine in incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`openFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> IO Handle` takes a `FilePath` and an `IOMode` and gives an `IO Handle`.

This means that

```
do
  args <- getArgs
  handle <- openFile args ReadMode
  ...
```

is claiming that `args` has type `FilePath`. However, the type of `getArgs :: IO [String]` means that `args` is a `[String]`, not a `FilePath`. This means that you are calling `openFile` with a list of strings rather than a file path.

To fix this, first we must know that `FilePath` is just a type synonym for `String`, which means that we must take an element of `args` rather than the whole list.

Here is an example that does so using pattern matching:

```
do
  [arg] <- getArgs
  handle <- openFile arg ReadMode
  ...
```

However, if the caller of your program provides the wrong number of arguments, this will cause an obscure runtime error (generated by `fail` from the pattern matching failure). A more robust program might handle these cases with more descriptive failure messages:

```
do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [] -> error "must supply a file to open"
    [arg] -> do handle <- openFile arg ReadMode
                ...
    _ -> error "too many arguments"
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is a simple matter of parsing, the following code works

```
args <- getArgs
let incomming = head args
handle ←  openFile incomming ReadMode
```

you have to parse the argument.